# Inherit two classes using swift

Tags: ios, swift, cosmicmind

Am using this library here

https://github.com/PaystackHQ/paystack-ios/blob/master/GUIDE.md am using there textfield

```
PSTCKPaymentCardTextField()
```

But i also want to use material deisgn textfield here 
   https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material

is there a way i can use both?

Comment: What is stopping you from using both controls in an app (apart from the fact that any control using `Material Design` does not follow the iOS design guidelines)?

Answer (score 0):

Protocol "inheritance" (it's actually conformation) is the way to do this, and/or using extensions.

There is no multi-parent inheritance for Swift Classes.

To "inherit" from multiple sources, in this situation, create extensions of Protocols with the necessary behaviours and properties, then conform to as many of them as you need, like this:

```
class NamedMyClass: ParentOfMyClass, FirstProtocol, SecondProtocol {
// all your custom implementations
}
```

Comment: So there is no way i can use the material design library along side paystack on the same textfield

Comment: There is a way but there is no easy way. You would really have to mesh both library's together.

Comment: Ok that will be going too far